# Listview with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, dynamic

I need a listview that adapts to the datasource and dynamically creates textbox controls.

Background: I upload an excel file, convert it to a datatable, display the values that were uploaded, allow for editing via textboxes, then finally insert it into a database.

The datasource will always be a datatable, but the number of columns will vary based on the excel file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with regular listview control. Well, at least I don't know about such possibility. I'm afraid you need to create a control yourself which will meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a DataGrid.

In Windows Forms:

```
dataGrid.DataSource = yourDataTable;
```

In WPF:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = yourDataTable.AsEnumerable();
```